# Issues creating, updating and retrieving data from Wowza Streaming Engine using PHP REST API?

Tags: php, wowza

I am getting started with the Wowza PHP Library and I am having trouble connecting to the streaming engine i have installed locally. As directed from https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-rest-library-php, I installed composer, created the config file with my server host and authentication settings

wowza_config.php

```
define("WOWZA_HOST","http://localhost:8087/v2");
define("WOWZA_SERVER_INSTANCE", "_defaultServer_");
define("WOWZA_VHOST_INSTANCE", "_defaultVHost_");
define("WOWZA_USERNAME", "admin");
define("WOWZA_PASSWORD", "admin");
```

Then when trying tests to retrieve data from the server for example:

index.php

```
<?php


require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
require_once("config/wowza_config.php");


// It is simple to create a setup object for transporting our settings
$setup = new Com\Wowza\Entities\Application\Helpers\Settings();
$setup->setHost(WOWZA_HOST);
$setup->setUsername(WOWZA_USERNAME);
$setup->setPassword(WOWZA_PASSWORD);

$sf = new Com\Wowza\Statistics($setup);
// get stats per application
$wowzaApplication = new Com\Wowza\Application($setup, 'vod');
// get total server stats
$server = new Com\Wowza\Server($setup, 'http://localhost:8087/v2');
$response = $sf->getServerStatistics($server);
// get stats historical for given application
// $response = $sf->getApplicationStatisticsHistory($wowzaApplication);
// $response = $sf->getApplicationStatistics($wowzaApplication);
// get incoming stream stats for given application


var_dump($response);
?>
```

I get the error

```
object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["message"]=> string(40) "The request requires user authentication" ["code"]=> string(3) "401" ["wowzaServer"]=> string(5) "4.7.7" ["success"]=> bool(false) }
```

I have triple checked to confirm the credentials I am using match those of the servers but cant figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: re the Fatal error: you can see trivially from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-rest-library-php/blob/master/src/Application.php) for a few seconds that the Application constructor requires quite a few arguments to be passed into it.

Comment: As for the other error, presumably you did something wrong compared to the examples (e.g. didn't provide username/password, or used invalid credentials, perhaps) but we can't be sure because you didn't show us _your_ code which would generate that error.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for your response, I had basically copied and pasted from the example and only made modifications to the server credentials.The code as you see it is what I tried to run. I did sort out the parameters issue but the authentication bit is still eluding me. I provided the admin credentials for the wowza server but it still rejects them

Comment: in the code "as you see it" you aren't passing the credentials (in the Settings object) into the Application constructor. The code we can see is the one causing the fatal error. We can't see the version which is causing the authentication issue...the code above won't get that far. So yeah please show us the code causing the second error, thanks.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, i corrected the error with passing the credentials. I have the test script I used and my config

Comment: and where did you find this sample? Just so I can compare with the "official" version?

Comment: @ADyson https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-rest-library-php/blob/master/tests/statistics.php

Comment: Hm, that doesn't include any config of the settings at all. I don't know if it's a test designed to fail, or a mistake, or you're supposed to add your own config...or perhaps the server can be configured to not require authentication, I don't know, I haven't used this product at all. But see my answer below - from tracing the code flow I've got a suggestion about what you might need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice: In your settings you don't set a value for "useDigest". So it defaults to false (see https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-rest-library-php/blob/master/src/Entities/Application/Helpers/Settings.php). Then when you call getServerStatistics() eventually it calls "sendRequest()" in the Wowza class (see https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-rest-library-php/blob/master/src/Wowza.php). And in this class, it only adds username and password to the request if "useDigest" is set to true in the settings:

```
if ($this->settings->isUseDigest()) {
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->settings->getUsername() . ':' . $this->settings->getPassword());
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
}
```

So I think it's not attaching the username and password to your request at all.

Therefore I suggest you add

```
$setup->setUseDigest(true);
```

to your code when you're configuring the Settings object, and that should help.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. Appreciate the help